# Anaconda Spyder Qt library error on launch

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda

When launching Spyder from the Anaconda python installation on Linux Mint 13 I get the following error:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40801) with this library (version 0x40805)
Aborted
```

$PATH is

```
   /home/ron/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Has anyone found a work around?

Anaconda web-site indicates that Spyder may not launch correctly on Linux machines.

```
http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/
```

*** Resolved
I am a little sheepish. Discovered that I installed Anaconda as sudo. Reinstalled as indicated in documentation and everything works fine. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: You need Qt 4.8.5 binaries it sounds. How to do that is up to you, but probably by compiling Qt 4.8.5.

Comment: Thanks John. I appreciate your help. I am impressed by the quality and quantity of help on stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set?

Comment: Asmeurer, I do not have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set. Shoud I set to the Anaconda lib folder?

Answer (score 3):

I use anaconda 1.8 on kubuntu alpha. It uses qt 4.8.5. I can see it with

```
find $ANACONDA/lib -name '*.4.8.5'
```

My system qt libs is 4.8.6. I can see it with

```
find /usr/lib -name "*so.4.8.6"
```

If Your system qt version is 4.8.5, and anaconda is 4.8.1 -- maybe You can just update anaconda? Try to run

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

**Edit**

It seems that the problem is spyder picking up Your system libraries. I tried to sheild the libs using evnironment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and various qt-related. But nothing works. However simple copying system libs to `$ANACONDA/lib` solves the problem.

Go to `$ANACONDA/lib` and move all `*.4.8*` files to another dir. Then go to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (are You using 64 bit?) and copy all `*.4.8*` to `$ANACONDA/lib`. That's it: run `spyder`!

[image]

The qtlibs are usually stored as files and links: for example if there's a `libQtGui.so.4.8.6` file then there's also a symbolic link `libQtGui.so.4.8`. You have to copy/move links too.

**Edit 2**:

There's [a suggestion](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/YzzgzXq3QHo%5B1-25-false%5D) to

```
unset QT_PLUGIN_PATH
```

I tried to set it to nothing `export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=`, but didn't try to `unset` it.

Comment: Adobe, the Anaconda lib folder contains several libQt... files including libQtCore.so.4.8.5. My anaconda version is 1.8. I ran the update process above but no change. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I gave up and did a complete install of python, ipython, ipython notebook, and spyder from scratch. All works fine now.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I did `conda update conda && conda update anaconda` and then `unset QT_PLUGIN_PATH`. On Fedora 20 x86_64.

Comment: The command `unset QT_PLUGIN_PATH` did the trick for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder dev here*) Just for the record, this is a [know bug](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/32) in Anaconda that hopefully will be fixed in its next version (to be released in October/2014).

Comment: Just updated to Anaconda 2.1.0 (released in Oct). Now spyder stops working... was working before update (Windows 64bit)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution was (inspired by @Adobe's answer) to go to the directory in which Anaconda was installed, then the subdirectory `lib` and to move all the files `libQt*` out of the way (I moved them to a temporary subdirectory I created for the purpose). Anaconda will now pick up the system libraries. I expect there will be a problem when I update Anaconda and it installs new Qt libraries, but that's for later.

My version is conda 3.9.1 with python 3.4.3 and qt 4.8.5, installed on Debian testing (current as of today) with libqtcore4 version 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3; the architecture is amd64.

Unsetting `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` and/or setting it to empty did work in the first instance, in that it allowed me to start spyder, but it has some disadvantages. Most importantly, whenever I tried to plot something using matplotlib and inline graphics, I got the error message "it seems the kernel died unexpectedly" instead of the plot I wanted.