# Error when trying to Launch Spyder using Anaconda

Tags: python, qt, plugins, anaconda, spyder

I'm on DigitalOcean VM and I'm trying to launch spyder, after installing Anaconda. I'm using Python 3.5.2 and Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit). The VM has Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64. When I try to launch spyder, I receive the following error:

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, xcb.

Think that I'm getting warmer. Based on the below, how would symbolic links be added to the correct libraries?

```
myuser@ubuntu-003-2x:~/anaconda3/plugins/platforms$ !422
apt-file search libSM.so.6
libsm6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
libsm6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6.0.1
myuser@ubuntu-003-2x:~/anaconda3/plugins/platforms$ !442
ldd libqxcb.so | grep not
libSM.so.6 => not found
libICE.so.6 => not found
libXrender.so.1 => not found
libSM.so.6 => not found
libICE.so.6 => not found
libXrender.so.1 => not found
```

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Do you have Xorg installed in your VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thank you for the responses. They helped solve the problem. Spyder will now launch! The solution is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install xcb

export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda 
unset QT_PLUGIN_PATH
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232872/4322543)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried that, but it didn't work. Weird how it works locally with Ubuntu and Anaconda, but not on the VM.